# Mongoose Schema default value for ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, odm

I have a collection of warehouse upgrades. It is predefined "template" collection containing for example max_capacity, level and price. Then I have warehouse_levels collection, this contains different indexes to warehouse_upgrades for different stored resources. But I can't create warehouse_level model, because I need to load _ids of warehouse_upgrades

```
WarehouseUpgrade = mongoose.model("warehouse_upgrade");

// find wheat upgrade containing level 0
WarehouseUpgrade.find({ type: "wheat", level: 0 }).exec(function (err, wheat) {

    var warehouseLevelSchema = Schema({
        wheat: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "warehouse_upgrade",
            default: wheat._id
        },
        ... more resources
    };
    var WarehouseLevel = mongoose.model("warehouse_level", warehouseLevelSchema);
}
```

When I want to call var WarehouseLevel = mongoose.model("warehouse_level"); interpreting this code throws error:

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "warehouse_level"
```

If I extract out schema definition from WarehouseUpgrade.find, then code works, but I can't set up default values for resource warehouses.

How can I set default value for ObjectId from different collection when I don't want to hardcode this values?

EDIT:
I load all schema definitions in file named mongoose.js:

```
var mongoose            = require("mongoose"),
Animal                  = require("../models/Animal");
Warehouse_upgrade       = require("../models/Warehouse_upgrade"),
Warehouse_level         = require("../models/Warehouse_level"),
User                    = require("../models/User"),
...

module.exports = function(config) {
    mongoose.connect(config.db);
    var db = mongoose.connection;

    // And now I call methods for creating my "templates"
    Warehouse_upgrade.createUpgrades();
    Animal.createAnimals();
    User.createDefaultUser();
}
```

MissingSchemaError occurs in model/User(username, hashed_password, email, warehouse_level,...) - every user has reference to his own document in warehouse_level.

```
// User
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    Warehouse_level = mongoose.model("warehouse_level");

// There are no users in DB, we need create default ones
// But first, we need to create collection document for warehouse_level
// and warehouse (not shown in this code snippet)
Warehouse_level.create({}, function (err, warehouseLevel) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
    // warehouse_level document is created, let's create user
    User.create({ username: ..., warehouse_level: warehouseLevel._id });
});
```

Comment: you might have to use an object inside your default key like default: {

Comment: Hi is Schema defined as : var Schema = DB.mongoose.Schema;

Comment: var Schema = DB.mongoose.Schema; throws error - Referrence Error - DB is not defined

Comment: well how is you Database defined where did you attach the database? Schema is not directly defined only the mongoose.Schema exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to achieve this is to create a method like "setDefaultIndexes"

```
var warehouseLevelSchema = mongoose.Schema({..});

warehouseLevelSchema.methods = {
    setDefaultUpgrades: function() {
        var self = this;
        WarehouseUpgrade.find({ level: 0 }).exec(function (err, collection) {
            for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
                var upgrade = collection[i];
                self[upgrade.type] = upgrade._id;
            }
            self.save();
        });
    }
};

var Warehouse_level = mongoose.model("warehouse_level", warehouseLevelSchema);
```

And call it after creation of new warehouse_level:

```
WarehouseLevel.create({}, function (err, warehouseLevel) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
    warehouseLevel.setDefaultUpgrades();
});
```